# 'Content-Disposition:' contains invalid characters returned by apache server

Tags: apache

Apache server works as a proxy server to backend Hybris. When user try to download PDF file, Apache returns below error in error log:

AH02429: Response header name 'Content-Disposition:' contains invalid characters, aborting request,

The backend server returns below header in respose to the apache server:

"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xxxx.pdf

Comment: The filename part should probably be quoted, `filename="xxxx.pdf"`

Comment: This was working fine, there was a Security update to Apache server and issue started there after. Old version was 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9 and new version is 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.15(Only Security update).

Comment: Well then go read the changelogs and try and find out what specifically has changed in that regard.

Comment: I could resolve this using directive '"HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe', but at the expense of security.

Comment: @Niranjankaup - Did you ever find fix for this issue?